# Den Unblöden gehört die Welt! - What does Unblöden mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

Media Markt has a campaign where they state that the world belongs to the "Unblöden", but I don't understand what "Unblöden" means and Google translate won't translate it.

So what does "Unblöden" mean?

Comment: `Unblöd` would be the noun of this made-up word and, translated into English you would have `unstupid`, meaning `smart`.

Comment: @user2693 Unblöd would be the adjective, not the noun. The noun could e.g. be der Unblöde :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well *Media Markt* has the slogan

> Ich bin doch nicht blöd!

which means as much as "I'm not stupid at all!". The meaning is that people who buy at *Media Markt* are not stupid.<sup>1</sup> "Unblöd" is a madeup word for the opposite of "blöd".

"Die Unblöden" are the people who are "unblöd" – something like "the non-stupid".

<sup>1</sup> <sub><sup>Even if I sometimes think the opposite might be the case</sup></sub>.

Comment: +1 for the footnote.

Comment: Media Markt? Ich bin doch nicht blöd!

Comment: Their ad's typography is interesting: giant **ICH**, giant **BLÖD**, tiny _bin doch nicht_...

Answer (score 3):

In the context of a Media Markt ad campaign, *unblöd* refers to a Media Markt customer. It's an allusion to Media Markt's long-running campaign "Ich bin doch nicht blöd" ("I am not stupid"), which put these words into Media Markt customers' mouths with (usually implicit) reference to the option of buying elsewhere. *Unblöd* is perhaps best translated as *non-stupid*, though the coinage is weird enough in German that *unstupid* might be a better choice to render that aspect in English as well.

Given how the company behind Media Markt and Saturn is taking its customers for fools with the fake competition it is enacting between the two chains, this add campaign is more than a bit ironic.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**
It actually means '*smart*'!
It's the german way of ironic '*understatement*'!

**Analogy:**
Something like '*not bad*' instead of '*good*'...

**Deduction:**
The formal idea behind it is probably the same as in *'Untoten'*, although this doesn't necessarily mean *'die Lebenden'* but rather in-between, in a state of a restless transition (neither - nor). So draw your own conclusion what this actually really means in the context of *'Unblöden'* ;-)

**Contextual Information:**
German humor is different in contrast to the British... -

Or do you understand: ***'Take a look at the wild SITE'***

I've been told that Brits don't really get it... ;-)
Germans consider this to be a very '*gelungen*' pun!

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?